# Possible to wait for an application window to appear?

Tags: java, process, wait, processbuilder

Common question: Is it possible to wait for an application window to appear til i go on with the code? The application was invoked by Java `Process/ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: The simplest thing I could imagine is to give the user a button in your Java app that says "the window has appeared."

Comment: AFAIK you can only access windows created by your java code from java. To access other processes' windows, you need native code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
      Process shell=builder.start();
     shell.waitFor();
```